# facebook/Twitter integration with jquery mobile for firefox os

Tags: facebook, cordova, firefox, jquery-mobile

I'm creating an application in firefox OS using jquery mobile and cordova.I have gone through a number of links where i have found plugins for only android and IOS. Are there any plugins for firefox OS.

I have followed https://developers.facebook.com/ and created an application,but there was no platform for webapp so i have created an app for website.I'm getting an error saying "Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration...".Now what urls can i give for "site url" and "mobile site url" in the app settings.

Answer (score 0):

For simplified facebook login, I used [openFb](https://github.com/ccoenraets/OpenFB)

There is a working exemple (working with cordova).

And the field you have to set right on [Facebook Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/) is (as mentionned in the read.me of openFB) :

> In the advanced settings, make sure you declare a "Valid OAuth redirect URI". For example, if during development you access your application from http://localhost/openfb/index.html, you must declare http://localhost/openfb/oauthcallback.html as a valid redirect URI. **Also add https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html as a Valid OAuth redirect URI for access from Cordova.**

Comment: I have setup the whole project(cordova+firefox OS) and in facebook developer site i have set those URLs.When I click the login button its going to the Mozilla firefox browser in mobile and opeing the facebook url and after successful login i'm getting a "success" screen and after that its not redirecting to app's index.html.I have used the redirects in manifest file also even then its not working.